# CoffeeScript Strange Behavior?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I came across this strange CoffeeScript behavior today.

```
arr = [1,2,3]
console.log 10 -8 
console.log arr.length -1
```

The second line is giving the correct output. But the the third line is resulting in a crash. What am I missing here?
You can test the code [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-coffeescript-online/).

Comment: It seems like `arr.length -1` is interpreted as `arr.length(-1)` which apparently throws "TypeError: arr.length is not a function". You can add a space between the `-` and `1`: `console.log arr.length - 1`

Comment: but arr.length is not a method. Why should it be interpreted as arr.length(-1) ?

Comment: I don't think CoffeeScript knows that `.length` is a property. My guess is it wrongly _assumes_ that `.length` is a method, that is being called with the argument `-1`, because this looks more like a negative number than an operation "subtract one". Disclaimer: I am not a CoffeeScript expert.

Comment: `o.p -1` is interpreted as `o.p(-1)`, `o.p - 1` is interpreted as `o.p - 1`. CoffeeScript doesn't know what sort of thing `o.p` is so it has to resolve the ambiguity in other ways, in this case it chooses consistency in whitespace around operators (i.e. `-1` is "negative one" whereas `- 1` is "subtract one"). I used to parenthesize all my method calls when I was writing CoffeeScript to avoid ambiguity. Check the transpired JavaScript: http://coffeescript.org/#try:a.length%20-1%0Aa.length%20-%201